# find flags: -exec rm -rf vs -delete

Tags: bash, find, directory, rm

I thought the flags I mentioned in the question are the same, but I get the following message with the former, but nothing with the latter:

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
find: `./practice4': No such file or directory
find: `./practice10': No such file or directory
find: `./practice7': No such file or directory
find: `./practice9': No such file or directory
find: `./practice1': No such file or directory
find: `./practice5': No such file or directory
find: `./practice3': No such file or directory
find: `./practice6': No such file or directory
find: `./practice2': No such file or directory
find: `./practice8': No such file or directory
```

Extra questions I have are:, is there an simpler code to delete all subdirectories? Is the order of deletion random? I created the directories using

```
$ mkdir practice{1..10}
```

Comment: You could use the BASH construct for iterating over files: `for dir in practice{1..10}; do rm -rf $dir; done`.

Comment: Even simpler:  `rm -rf practice{1..10}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the GNU find manual:

> If your `find' command removes directories, you may find that you get
>   a spurious error message when`find' tries to recurse into a directory
>   that has now been removed.  Using the `-depth' option will normally
>   resolve this problem.

Other questions:

- The simplicity of the command depends on your situation, which in the listed case would be: `rm -rf practice*`.
- IIRC, the processing order of the files depends on the file system.

Answer (score 4):

[Thor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65537/find-flags-exec-rm-rf-vs-delete/65538#65538) has already explained why you're getting this error and how to fix it when using `find`.

Calling `find` with `-mindepth 1` is pointless unless you have additional conditions that can't be expressed in a shell script. What you're trying to do can be written

```
rm -rf */
```

as long as the current directory doesn't contain any directory whose name begins with `.` (which wouldn't be matched by `*`) or symbolic links to directories (which your `find` command excludes but the shell snippet above includes).

Comment: In bash you can include .* (without . and ..) by setting `GLOBIGNORE=.`