# Why does `find -type d -exec rmdir {} \;` command produce "No such file or directory message"

Tags: linux, find, directory, rm, exec

For testing purposes, I created the following directories.

```
user@linux:~$ mkdir dir0{1..3}

user@linux:~$ ls -l
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4.0K Mei  31 10:45 dir01
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4.0K Mei  31 10:45 dir02
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4.0K Mei  31 10:45 dir03
user@linux:~$
```

Then, I removed it with `find -exec`

```
user@linux:~$ find -type d -exec rmdir {} \;
rmdir: failed to remove '.': Invalid argument
find: ‘./dir02’: No such file or directory
find: ‘./dir01’: No such file or directory
find: ‘./dir03’: No such file or directory
user@linux:~$
```

The directories were removed, I verified it.

```
user@linux:~$ ls -l
total 0
user@linux:~$
```

My questions are:

1) I don't understand why does the messages were there. Any idea why?

```
rmdir: failed to remove '.': Invalid argument
find: ‘./dir02’: No such file or directory
```

I don't see this kind of error with `rmdir`

```
user@linux:~$ mkdir dir0{1..3}
user@linux:~$ 

user@linux:~$ ls -l
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4.0K Mei  31 22:58 dir01
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4.0K Mei  31 22:58 dir02
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4.0K Mei  31 22:58 dir03
user@linux:~$ 

user@linux:~$ rmdir *
user@linux:~$ 

user@linux:~$ ls -l
total 0
user@linux:~$
```

2) Is it possible to remove these messages?

Comment: Likely related: [find flags: -exec rm -rf vs -delete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65537/find-flags-exec-rm-rf-vs-delete)

Comment: Ah, indeed, the accepted answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65554/88983 is about exactly the same, and even suggests a real-world solution.

Comment: WARNING: `rmdir` will only remove a directory if it has no files/directories under it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What presumably happens is that, with the `-exec ... \;` construct,
find does its work step by step:

- walk the directory tree, finding entries that match `-type d`, and
- run `rmdir` on such entries as soon as they are found.

This means that, in your example, find will look at `dir01`, keep it
in mind as a directory to enter later, then run `rmdir` on it, and
then, when trying to recurse into `dir01`, fail because it does not
exist anymore.

Running with `-exec rmdir {} +` should help in this instance: a single
call to `rmdir dir01 dir02 dir03` will be emitted. This gets rid of
the last three error messages.

The error message about `.` is because, well, `.`, the current
directory is indeed a directory, but not one that `rmdir` can delete,
because it is not empty. Use `-min-depth` to stop considering it,
making the command:

```
find -mindepth 1 -type d -exec rmdir {} +
```

This is not perfect; nested directories or a large number of matching
directories could still cause error messages to be printed, but this
should work in the simple case from the question.

Answer (score 3):

You get those "No such file or directory" errors from `find` because `find` is trying to enter directories that it has just removed.  It will by default apply its actions to all matching things in the directory that it's currently visiting before continuing into the subdirectories.

Add `-depth` to the invocation of `find` to  make `find` do a depth-first search of its search paths, which in turn means that if you execute `rmdir` on a directory, it will already have visited it and won't try to visit it again.

The `-depth` option is implied when using `-delete` for this reason (in implementations of `find` that has `-delete`).

```
find . -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} \;
```

`-depth` is a standard option for the `find` utility.

Note that `rmdir` only works on empty directories. If you have lots of non-empty directories, the above command would produce lots of error messages.

Instead, if your `find` supports it, use `-empty`:

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

This would delete empty directories.

With a `find` that does not have the non-standard `-delete` nor `-emtpy`:

```
find . -depth -type d -exec sh -c '
    for dirpath do
        set -- "$dirpath"/*
        [ ! -e "$1" ] && rmdir "$dirpath"
    done' sh {} +
```

This would test whether the found directories were empty, and if they were, they would be deleted.

That's a long piece of code to avoid seeing some error messages due to directories being non-empty, but any error messages that *are* produced will hopefully be more interesting to look at as they would probably be "permission denied" errors. Redirecting the errors to `/dev/null` in the first `find` command at the top would have hidden such errors.